# Getting garbage values with pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to add two initialized arrays in a third array via pointers, but I'm still getting garbage values. Here's my code:

```
void add(float*, float*, float*);
int main()
{
float arr1[SIZE] = {1,2,3,4};
float arr2[SIZE] = {4,3,2,1};
float arr3[SIZE];
add(arr3, arr2, arr1);
for(int q=0;q<SIZE;q++){
    cout<<*(arr3+q);
}
return 0;
}
void add(float* ptr, float* ptr1, float* ptr2){
*ptr++  = *(ptr1++) + *(ptr2++);
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: why are you spitting out values from arr3? You never initialized it. This is like "I went to the restaurant and ordered a salad. They served me a salad, which is exactly what I wanted. Why did they serve me a salad?"

Comment: m using pointers to store values in arr3, first i passed it as argument in add functions, then added ptr1 and ptr2 in ptr, which is pointing to arr3;

Comment: no. you're storing into `arr1`, in your add function, arr3 is in `ptr2`.

Comment: i Noticed that and i corrected it, but still m having same problem.

Comment: okay i solved it :) 
appreciate your help

Comment: *.. pointers, but I'm still getting garbage values*. You and every Adobe application ever released. Don't feel bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for your `add` function:

```
void add(float* ptr, float* ptr1, float* ptr2){
   *ptr++  = *(ptr1++) + *(ptr2++);
}
```

This code seems like it's missing a loop that would walk the pointers forward across the array elements, especially given that you're changing the values of `ptr`, `ptr1`, and `ptr2` without ever using the adjusted values.

Did you mean something like this?

```
void add(float* ptr, float* ptr1, float* ptr2){
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      *ptr++  = *(ptr1++) + *(ptr2++);
   }
}
```

Or, for clarity, perhaps something like this?

```
void add(float* ptr, float* ptr1, float* ptr2){
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      ptr[i] = ptr1[i] + ptr2[i];
}
```

Without the loop, you only update the very first element of the output array, which probably explains why you're seeing garbage.

Comment: Thanks for help :)